# Candy Distribution--Didnt get this one

Tags: algorithm

It is Jawa's birthday today. His each friend tells him the least number of toffees he wants. Later, his friends together decided that if he is able to satisfy the condition of atleast one of his friends than they will buy him a $1000 gift.
You have to help Jawa to decide the minimum number of toffees he need to buy to satisfy his friends conditions. This minimum number of toffees in any possible distribution should satisfy his friends condition.

Input: 
First line contains a single integer T denoting number of test cases.
First line of each test case contains a single integer N denoting number of his friends.
Second line of each test case contains N space separated integers denoting the least number of toffees his each friend want.

Output: 
For each test case output single integer denoting minimum number of toffees he needs to buy to satisfy the condition.

```
Constraints:
1<=T<=10
1<=N<=100000
1<=Ai<=1000000000
```

Examples------------------------------

```
Sample Input (Plaintext Link)
2
3
8 6 9
1
4
Sample Output (Plaintext Link)
21
4
```

I cant understand how can the first input `8 6 9` give `21` as output.Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key idea is that the distribution of candy is adversarial. That is the friends divide the candy in an attempt to make sure that none of them have the minimum that they requested. 
With the friends requesting 8,6,9 this is 21. Twenty would not suffice as they could divide it out as 7,5,8.

If my reading is correct then here are some more test cases

```
Requests | Minimums
1        | 1    
1 1      | 1
1 2      | 2
2 2      | 3
```